Highlighting not working when using Java elasticsearch api
When I use the following query using CURL I successfully get highlights:
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Angular"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {
        "pre_tags": [
          "<mark>"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
          "</mark>"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

But when I use the following StringQuery in Java, it returns no highlights.
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public void searchResume(@RequestParam(name = "search") String query) {
        Query stringQuery = new StringQuery("""
                {
                    "query_string": {
                      "query": "$QUERY"
                    }
                }
                "highlight": {
                    "fields": {
                        "*": {
                            "pre_tags": ["<mark>"],
                            "post_tags": ["</mark>"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            """.replace("$QUERY", query));
        var result = operations.search(stringQuery, Resume.class);
        result.getSearchHits().forEach(sh -> System.out.println(sh.getHighlightFields()));

Does someone know how to get highlighting using the StringQuery api?
